# Is there a way to execute commands remotely using gcloud compute ssh utility

Tags: ssh, virtual-machine, gcloud, private-network

I know it is possible to execute commands remotely using ssh (in a file) like so;

```
#!/bin/sh

ssh ${USER}@${SERVER_IP} <<EOF
 cd ${PROJECT_PATH}
 git pull
 exit
EOF
```

my question is this: it possible to do the same with gcloud compute ssh? I mean;

```
gcloud compute ssh vm-internal --zone us-central1-c --tunnel-through-iap << EOF
...
...
EOF
```

**PS: The instance is private with no external IP hence the use of iap**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As long as you can ssh onto the instance, you should be able to:

```sh
gcloud compute ssh .... --command="bash -s" <<EOF
echo "Hello Freddie"
ls -l
EOF
```

You can test this (thanks to `gcloud` consistency using Cloud Shell):

```sh
gcloud alpha cloud-shell ssh --command="bash -s" <<EOF
echo "Hello Freddie"
ls
EOF
```

> **NOTE** you may not need the `-s` but I think it's preferred

Yields:

```
Automatic authentication with GCP CLI tools in Cloud Shell is disabled. To enable, please rerun command with `--authorize-session` flag.
Hello Freddie
Projects
README-cloudshell.txt -> /google/devshell/README-cloudshell.txt
stackoverflow
```